React 18 update - I need opinions on nuking an Enzyme legacy test coverage to use RTL instead
I just updated a legacy React code (born 5 years ago and no one never updated). What happens is that Enzyme does not run in the 18.x React versions and I had to nuke all tests, for now. The project is a huge front-end CRUD system that mostly was carrying unit-tests (and very poorly). While navigating through the project, I don't see anything weird or any strange behavior that would make me uncomfortable. I just need opinions on what would be the your advices to do this migration to PRD. I raised Bugsnag to keep monitoring if anything goes wrong in the background, and I would like to ask some guidance on it to move on. Maybe recommended tools that could check potential breaks (let's say in dependencies that were updated fine), or something like that. Oh, and my plan is also to make sure all files are not .js, but .ts, and I will cover all of them with snapshots for next enhancements security reasons. And finally, there is no way I get back to 17 to use enzyme-adapter-react-17 and maintain both tests tools. Thank you very much for listening.
